# bash - passing optional arguments to script - parametername + string_value

Tags: bash, shell

i use a script that accepts parameter. parameters are optional and may occur in any order.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name: test.sh
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ ! -z "$var" ]   && ([ $var = "--example" ] || [ $var = "-e" ]); then
        echo "example"
    elif [ ! -z "$var" ]   && ([ $var = "--project" ] || [ $var = "-p" ]); then
        echo "project with string xxxxxxx"
    fi
done
```

in this simple example, you could call it like follows (some examples):

```
# this will echo example
./test.sh --example 
# this will echo project with string xxxxxxx
./test.sh --project
# this will echo both example and project with string xxxxxxx
./test.sh --example --project
```

NOW, what i want to achieve is that i can do something like this (warning, this is pseuco code):

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name: test.sh
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ ! -z "$var" ]   && ([ $var = "--example" ] || [ $var = "-e" ]); then
        echo "example"
    elif [ ! -z "$var" ]   && ([ $var = "--project" ] || [ $var = "-p" ]); then
        echo "project with string $VAR_VALUE"
    fi
done



# this will echo example
./test.sh --example 
# this will echo project with string myproject1
./test.sh --project="myproject1" 
# this will echo both example and project with string myproject2
./test.sh --example --project="myproject2"
```

can someone help me rewrite it so this will work somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getopt`. It handles short and long options, allows for both `--long value` and `--long=value`, decomposes `-abc` into `-a -b -c`, understands `--` to end option parsing, and more.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=$(getopt -o ep: -l example,project: -n "$0" -- "$@") || exit
eval set -- "$args"

while [[ $1 != '--' ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -e|--example) echo "example";      shift 1;;
        -p|--project) echo "project = $2"; shift 2;;

        # shouldn't happen unless we're missing a case
        *) echo "unhandled option: $1" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift  # skip '--'

echo "remaining non-option arguments: $@"
```

Comment: What does the getopt -n option do?  I looked up the man page, but don't understand it.

Comment: @jrahhali If the user makes a mistake with the arguments getopt will print "progname: error message". `-n` tells it what "progname" is so it looks like the error message is coming from your program.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible path toward parsing argument list

1. Build custom option parser
2. use getopt, using 'long options'

The first approach is relatively simple (at this time). Using `case` instead of `if` to handle variants:

```
last_arg=
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [ "$last_arg" = "-p" ] ; then
        VAR_VALUE=$arg ;
        last_arg=
        echo "project with string $VAR_VALUE"
        continue
    fi
    case "$arg" in
        -e | --example)
            echo "example" ;;
        -p)
            last_arg=$arg ;;
        --project=*)
            VAR_VALUE=${arg#*=}
            echo "project with string $VAR_VALUE" ;;
        *) ERROR-MESSAGE ;;
    esac
done
exit
```

The BETTER approach is to leverage existing code. In particular getopt, which can handle long options:

```
#! /bin/bash
if T=$(getopt -o ep: --long 'example,project:' -n ${0#*/} -- "$@") ; then
        eval set -- "$T"
else
        exit $?
fi
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] ; do
        case "$1" in
                -e | --example)
                        echo "example"
                        ;;
                -p | --project)
                        shift
                        VAR_VALUE=$1
                        echo "project with string $VAR_VALUE"
                        ;;
                --)
                        break
                        ;;
                *) echo "ERROR:$1" ;;
        esac
        shift
done
```